# Is it OK to use AWT with JavaFx?

Tags: java, awt, javafx-2

I need some functionality that I cannot find currently in JavaFX.  Like the Robot or the Tray Icon.

I know these tools do work with JavaFx applications.
But is it ok to use them?  Are there any considerations that I should care of?

Comment: I'm not an JavaFx expert, but for me it seem to be a very solid solution. Can't complain... Please not that I'm programming on a win-system for win-systems.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Generally it's not advised.

N.B.:

- using any AWT from JavaFX will start whole AWT stack which can increase memory/proc consumption.
- there could be threading conflicts between Glass (FX UI stack) and AWT, especially on Mac. So it maybe worth using Swing Interoperability approach for your app as `JFXPanel` is aware how to handle that conflicts.
- you can use Glass robot instead of AWT one (although it's not public API and may be changed in future):

  ```
  Robot robot = com.sun.glass.ui.Application.GetApplication().createRobot();
  robot.mouseMove(10, 30);
  robot.mousePress(1);
  ```

Comment: Thank you Sergey.  And for the Tray icon,  do you have news of some compatible technology that can be used?

Comment: The tray icon functionality is not implemented yet. You can track the status of this feature over here: https://javafx-jira.kenai.com/browse/RT-24251

Comment: Updated link to JavaFX tray icon feature request mentioned by @Petr: https://bugs.openjdk.java.net/browse/JDK-8092115

Comment: JavaFX 11 now has the public [`javafx.scene.robot.Robot`](https://openjfx.io/javadoc/11/javafx.graphics/javafx/scene/robot/Robot.html) class.

Comment: I provide a small wrapper library for easily adding a tray icon in JavaFX apps. It keeps developers from having to touch the dreaded AWT API.  [FXTrayIcon](https://github.com/dustinkredmond/FXTrayIcon)