# JavaFX 2.1: Toolkit not initialized

Tags: javafx-2

My application is Swing-based. I would like to introduce JavaFX and configure it to render a Scene on a secondary display.
I could use a JFrame to hold a JFXPanel which could hold a JFXPanel but I would like to achieve this with JavaFX API.

Subclassing com.sun.glass.ui.Application and using Application.launch(this) is not an option because the invoking thread would be blocked.

When instantiating a Stage from Swing EDT, the error I get is:

```
java.lang.IllegalStateException: Toolkit not initialized
```

Any pointers?

---

EDIT: Conclusions

**Problem**: Non-trivial Swing GUI application needs to run JavaFX components. Application's startup process initializes the GUI after starting up a dependent service layer.

**Solutions**

**Subclass JavaFX Application class** and run it in a separate thread e.g.:

```
public class JavaFXInitializer extends Application {
    @Override
    public void start(Stage stage) throws Exception {
        // JavaFX should be initialized
        someGlobalVar.setInitialized(true);
    }
}
```

Sidenote: Because Application.launch() method takes a `Class<? extends Application>` as an argument, one has to use a global variable to signal JavaFX environment has been initialized.

Alternative approach: **instantiate JFXPanel in Swing Event Dispatcher Thread**:

```
final CountDownLatch latch = new CountDownLatch(1);
SwingUtilities.invokeLater(new Runnable() {
    public void run() {
        new JFXPanel(); // initializes JavaFX environment
        latch.countDown();
    }
});
latch.await();
```

By using this approach the calling thread will wait until JavaFX environment is set up.

Pick any solution you see fit. I went with the second one because it doesn't need a global variable to signal the initialization of JavaFX environment and also doesn't waste a thread.

Comment: N.B.: recommended solution to work with JavaFX from Swing application is to create JFXPanel and pass JavaFX scene to jfxPanel.setScene() method. See http://docs.oracle.com/javafx/2/api/javafx/embed/swing/JFXPanel.html

Comment: @SergeyGrinev: Well, but as some Components have issues being used within JFXPanel, another way to work wit JavaFX 2 from Swing is highly appreciated.

Comment: Hi. Which components have issues?

Comment: The HTMLEditor Component doesn't accept the Enter-Key when inside of a JFXPanel - that's in my eyes a showstopping issue for an editor component. See also here: http://javafx-jira.kenai.com/browse/RT-20887

Comment: Here's a simplification using Java 8 that turns it into a one-liner:
SwingUtilities.invokeAndWait(() -> new JFXPanel());

Answer (score 24, accepted):

Found a solution. If I just create a JFXPanel from Swing EDT before invoking JavaFX Platform.runLater it works.
I don't know how reliable this solution is, I might choose JFXPanel and JFrame if turns out to be unstable.

```
public class BootJavaFX {

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        SwingUtilities.invokeLater(new Runnable() {
            @Override
            public void run() {
                new JFXPanel(); // this will prepare JavaFX toolkit and environment
                Platform.runLater(new Runnable() {
                    @Override
                    public void run() {
                        StageBuilder.create()
                                .scene(SceneBuilder.create()
                                        .width(320)
                                        .height(240)
                                        .root(LabelBuilder.create()
                                                .font(Font.font("Arial", 54))
                                                .text("JavaFX")
                                                .build())
                                        .build())
                                .onCloseRequest(new EventHandler<WindowEvent>() {
                                    @Override
                                    public void handle(WindowEvent windowEvent) {
                                        System.exit(0);
                                    }
                                })
                                .build()
                                .show();
                    }
                });
            }
        });
    }
}
```

Comment: if you are having JFXPanel already, why you don't want to put FX code inside?

Comment: In this solution am only using JFXPanel as a workaround to get the JavaFX environment running. I would have liked something like Platform.initialize() in JavaFX.

Comment: You need to do all that to make it work??, ridiculous.

Comment: In the demos, it always looks so easy

Answer (score 24):

Since JavaFX 9, you can run JavaFX application without extending [`Application`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/9/docs/api/javafx/application/Application.html) class, by calling [`Platform.startup()`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/9/docs/api/javafx/application/Platform.html#startup-java.lang.Runnable-):

```
Platform.startup(() ->
{
    // This block will be executed on JavaFX Thread
});
```

> This method starts the JavaFX runtime.

Comment: This worked great for me when using Groovy and Spock too. Just run it in the `setup()`-method.

Answer (score 21):

The only way to work with JavaFX is to subclass Application or use JFXPanel, exactly because they prepare env and toolkit.

Blocking thread can be solved by using `new Thread(...)`.

Although I suggest to use JFXPanel if you are using JavaFX in the same VM as Swing/AWT, you can find more details here: [Is it OK to use AWT with JavaFx?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11119227/is-it-ok-to-use-awt-with-javafx)

Comment: I was avoiding new Thread(...) stuff because my application is Swing based. Thanks for the hint.

Comment: My application has a specific startup routine. The GUI initialisation takes place in a later stage, invoked from the main thread. I was looking into starting JavaFX environment and getting a notification when it's done. Using Application.launch it's not a solution for me because it blocks the calling thread.

Comment: I still don't see any conflicts with using Thread. And if you wanna stick with this approach test in on Mac before production.

Comment: I develop mainly on Mac and this approach works fine as long as the main thread doesn't exit. I'm not saying there is a conflict by using a new Thread, it's just that I don't prefer blocking a thread. In my opinion both solutions are workarounds for an api call that's missing in the JavaFX environment/toolkit.

Comment: Summed everything up in the first post. Thanks for your feedback.

Answer (score 8):

I checked the source code and this is to initialize it

```
com.sun.javafx.application.PlatformImpl.startup(()->{});
```

and to exit it

```
com.sun.javafx.application.PlatformImpl.exit();
```

Comment: Calling internal `com.sun` classes like this does not work on Java 9+ because the package is not exported.

Comment: I was able to use the approach in this answer successfully when building and executing tests with JDK 11, specifically Azul Community JDK 11.0.11+9 x86_64, and OpenJFX 16, on Windows 10 64-bit. I put the call to `PlatformImpl.startup` in the `@BeforeClass setUpOnce` method, and the call to `PlatformImpl.exit` in the `tearDownOnce` method in my JUnit 4 test suite. These `com.sun` method calls result in only a warning at runtime

Answer (score 4):

I used following when creating unittests for testing javaFX tableview updates

```
public class testingTableView {
        @BeforeClass
        public static void initToolkit() throws InterruptedException
        {
            final CountDownLatch latch = new CountDownLatch(1);
            SwingUtilities.invokeLater(() -> {
                new JFXPanel(); // initializes JavaFX environment
                latch.countDown();
            });

            if (!latch.await(5L, TimeUnit.SECONDS))
                throw new ExceptionInInitializerError();
        }

        @Test
        public void updateTableView() throws Exception {

            TableView<yourclassDefiningEntries> yourTable = new TableView<>();
            .... do your testing stuff

        }
    }
```

even though this post is not test related, then it helped me to get my unittest to work

- without the BeforeClass initToolkit, then the instantiation of TableView in the unittest would yield a message of missing toolkit

Comment: Thanks for this... I'm also trying to figure out JavaFX and testing.  But most non-trivial JavaFX operations produce "IllegalStateException: This operation is permitted on the event thread only;".  And running inside a `Plaform.runLater()` `Runnable` doesn't work: with Swing it was always necessary to use `EventQueue.invokeAndWait()` - otherwise the test would end before the Runnable ran.  Isn't it the case that you pretty much have to use sthg like TestFX for JavaFX testing?

Comment: PS of course you can use latches to achieve this "waiting for a Runnable to end"... but it's hardly elegant.

Comment: @mikerodent, I agree it is not elegant to use latches to wait for a utility to be present, however when it comes to being dependent on external entities, then this is perhaps not as clumsy as it could be

Answer (score 4):

There's also way to initialize toolkit explicitly, by calling:
`com.sun.javafx.application.PlatformImpl#startup(Runnable)`

Little bit hacky, due to using *Impl, but is useful, if you don't want to use `Application` or `JXFPanel` for some reason.

*re-posting myself from [this post](https://stackoverflow.com/a/38883432/3504373)*

Comment: I want to give this answer a standing ovation!  I am writing an application with the intent of having two UI the first is in FX, the second non-graphic.  My model uses FX collections.  Without this you can't use the collections and not have a graphics element.

Comment: This also solves a race condition when starting the model before the graphics.  So thanks to no end!

Comment: Removes the needs to subclass stuff and runs before the UI Thread. Clearly what I needed to preprare before the GUI-Thread (please google! Remember me...). Thanks a bunch!

Comment: Calling internal `com.sun` classes like this does not work on Java 9+ because the package is not exported.

Answer (score 0):

```
private static Thread thread;

public static void main(String[] args) {

    Main main = new Main();
    startup(main);
    thread = new Thread(main);
    thread.start();
}

public static void startup(Runnable r) {
    com.sun.javafx.application.PlatformImpl.startup(r);
}

@Override
public void run() {
    SoundPlayer.play("BelievexBelieve.mp3");
}
```

This is my solution. The class is named Main and implements Runnable. Method `startup(Runnable r)` is the key.

Comment: Calling internal `com.sun` classes like this does not work on Java 9+ because the package is not exported.

Answer (score 0):

Using Jack Lin’s answer, I found that it fired off the run() twice.  With a few modifications that also made the answer more concise, I offer the following;

```
import com.sun.javafx.application.PlatformImpl;

public class MyFxTest implements Runnable {

    public static void main(String[] args) {

        MyFxTest main = new MyFxTest();
        PlatformImpl.startup((Runnable) main);
    }

    @Override
    public void run() {

        // do your testing;
        System.out.println("Here 'tis");
        System.exit(0); // Optional
    }
}
```