# JavaFX: "Toolkit" not initialized when trying to play an mp3 file through MediaPlayer class

Tags: java, media-player, javafx-2

I'm trying to make a simple mp3 play in the background of my program using the following:

```
Media med = new Media(getClass().getResource("intro.mp3").toExternalForm());
MediaPlayer mPlayer = new MediaPlayer(med);
mPlayer.play();
```

The intro.mp3 file is placed in the bin folder of my package, along with the other .class files.

The problem is that my program terminates with:

```
Exception in thread "main" java.lang.IllegalStateException: Toolkit not initialized
```

Full termination log is:

```
Device "Intel(R) HD Graphics Family" (\\.\DISPLAY1) initialization failed : 
WARNING: bad driver version detected, device disabled. Please update your driver to at least version 8.15.10.2302

Exception in thread "main" java.lang.IllegalStateException: Toolkit not initialized
    at com.sun.javafx.application.PlatformImpl.runLater(PlatformImpl.java:153)
    at com.sun.javafx.application.PlatformImpl.runLater(PlatformImpl.java:148)
    at javafx.application.Platform.runLater(Platform.java:52)
    at javafx.scene.media.MediaPlayer.init(MediaPlayer.java:450)
    at javafx.scene.media.MediaPlayer.<init>(MediaPlayer.java:365)
    at PokerApp.<init>(PokerApp.java:33)
    at PokerApp.main(PokerApp.java:105)
```

Anybody have any ideas as per the cause of the problem?

Answer (score 28, accepted):

`JavaFX` performs "hidden" initialization on start. Running `MediaPlayer` doesn't trigger initialization.

The easiest ways to trigger it are:

- have `Application.launch()` executed
- have `Application` based program being run from jar packaged by fx [ant tasks](http://docs.oracle.com/javafx/2/deployment/javafx_ant_task_reference.htm) (e.g. built from Netbeans JavaFX project)
- have [JFXPanel](http://docs.oracle.com/javafx/2/api/javafx/embed/swing/JFXPanel.html) started
- call [`Platform.startup(Runnable)`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/10/docs/api/javafx/application/Platform.html#startup(java.lang.Runnable)) (Java 9+)

Comment: Will try it out and mark the question as the correct one if it works after I get home. Merry christmas to you, mister Sergey, and thank you for your answers in both my questions.

Comment: I placed a single JFXPanel fxPanel = new JFXPanel(); in my constructor and everything worked out fine.

Is it recommended I use a JFXPanel instead of a JPanel or a Container when I use JavaFX with SWING?

Comment: you can put fx nodes only into JFXPanel, so it's definitely recommended to use it if you want to have Swing app with JavaFX features.

Comment: What would I do if, say, I was running headless?

Comment: I don't think JavaFX supports headless

Answer (score 15):

To avoid initialization Exception you have to either invoke **Application.launch()** method or simply **instantiate a new JFXPanel() class** **(even if it isn’t used for anything).** This will initiate **JavaFxRuntime** when application is started

To instantiate JFXPanel add below line in your code

```
 final JFXPanel fxPanel = new JFXPanel();
```

Import following package

```
import javafx.embed.swing.JFXPanel;
```

Answer (score 5):

There's also way to initialize toolkit explicitly, by calling:
`com.sun.javafx.application.PlatformImpl#startup(Runnable)`

Little bit hacky, due to using *Impl, but is useful, if you don't want to use `Application` or `JXFPanel` for some reason.

Answer (score 3):

see http://www.programcreek.com/java-api-examples/index.php?api=com.sun.javafx.application.PlatformImpl

```
com.sun.javafx.application.PlatformImpl.startup(()->{});
```