# IllegalStateException when using the Tray Notification in java Fx?

Tags: java, exception, javafx, notifications

I am trying to implement a pop upp notification in JavaFx I am using this [lib](https://github.com/PlusHaze/TrayNotification/tree/master/out)
and according to that tutorial wrote this code:

```
    String title = "Well done boy!!";
    String message = "You've successfully created your first Tray Notification";

    TrayNotification tray = new TrayNotification();
    tray.setTitle(title);
    tray.setMessage(message);
    tray.setNotificationType(NotificationType.SUCCESS);
    tray.showAndWait();
```

but the code is throwing an Exception:

> Caused by: java.lang.IllegalStateException: Toolkit not initialized
>     at com.sun.javafx.application.PlatformImpl.runLater(Unknown Source)
>     at com.sun.javafx.application.PlatformImpl.runLater(Unknown Source)
>     at
>   com.sun.javafx.application.PlatformImpl.setPlatformUserAgentStylesheet(Unknown
>   Source)   at
>   com.sun.javafx.application.PlatformImpl.setDefaultPlatformUserAgentStylesheet(Unknown
>   Source)   at javafx.scene.control.Control.(Unknown Source)    ...
>   15 more

Any suggetion why?

please note, the original code example is [implemented like](https://github.com/PlusHaze/TrayNotification):

```
tray.setNotification(notification);
```

where notification is

but some how I can not import the class

```
 Notification notification = Notifications.SUCCESS;
```

Comment: Do you invoke the code in Platform.runLater ?

Comment: nope, in the main method of eclipse the code is runned as in the example posted above....

Comment: Subclass `Application` or create a new `new JFXPanel()` to have the Toolkit initialized. See http://stackoverflow.com/questions/11273773/javafx-2-1-toolkit-not-initialized and http://stackoverflow.com/questions/14025718/javafx-toolkit-not-initialized-when-trying-to-play-an-mp3-file-through-mediap

Answer (score 0):

try to use constructor for creating.ıt works for me that way.
Did you add the library from the module settings?

Ex:

```
 TrayNotification tray = new TrayNotification("Test", "mesaj", NotificationType.SUCCESS);        
    tray.showAndWait();
```