# How to play a sound file in Java

Tags: java, file, audio

I searched in many forums and YouTube tutorials for an easy bit of code to just play a sound file (.mp3), but everything I found won't work for me.

I always get the exception that it can't find the file or that something else is wrong, but it always ends in an exception.

Is there something that I have to configure first maybe?

-edit-
**I tried the following code again to show what exeption i get:**

[Here is my code](https://i.stack.imgur.com/mrU3Z.jpg)

**After adding the JFXPanel i got the exeption:** Exception in thread "main" MediaException: MEDIA_UNAVAILABLE : D:\bip.mp3 (The System cant find the File) //
*and yes, i checked if the path is correct.*

Comment: this was the first thing i searched http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6045384/playing-mp3-and-wav-in-java

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Playing .mp3 and .wav in Java?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6045384/playing-mp3-and-wav-in-java)

Comment: Possible duplicate of [JavaFX: "Toolkit" not initialized when trying to play an mp3 file through MediaPlayer class](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/14025718/javafx-toolkit-not-initialized-when-trying-to-play-an-mp3-file-through-mediap)

Comment: @phihag I found this post already but i tried the solutions and it still doesnt work ... i still get the same result. maybe i did something wrong ?

Comment: @CRHS The code you linked to (in an image instead of posting it here - why?) does not include any of the solutions.

Comment: i wanted to show whats not working and i posted is as a picture link because it wont work with the codeblock stuff from stack overflow ... dont know why.

Answer (score 2):

To avoid initialization Exception you have to either invoke **Application.launch()** method or simply **instantiate a new JFXPanel() class** (even if it isn’t used for anything). This will initiate JavaFxRuntime when application is started

so add below line in your code

```
 final JFXPanel fxPanel = new JFXPanel();
```

Import following package

```
import javafx.embed.swing.JFXPanel;
```

Now your code will look like this

```
import java.io.File;
import javafx.embed.swing.JFXPanel;
import javafx.scene.media.Media;
import javafx.scene.media.MediaPlayer;

public class Test {

public static void main(String args[]) {

    final JFXPanel fxPanel = new JFXPanel();
    String bip = "D://bip.mp3";  //sound file path
    Media hit = new Media(new File(bip).toURI().toString());
    MediaPlayer mediaPlayer = new MediaPlayer(hit);
    mediaPlayer.play();

  }
}
```

Comment: Now i got this: Exception in thread "main" MediaException: MEDIA_UNAVAILABLE : D:\Waves.mp3 (The System cant found the File)

Comment: Check media file name and path because when I tried by changing bip.mp3 to bip1.mp3(no such file is there) I got the same error, so please check file name with proper cases.

Comment: Thats wired ... i checked it 5 times but still the same result ... i even choose the same name for my file to be sure :(

Comment: try to add media like this  Media hit = new Media("file:///D://bip.mp3"); Three slashes after file.Reference https://superuser.com/questions/352133/what-is-the-reason-that-file-urls-start-with-three-slashes-file-etc

Answer (score 0):

Maybe posting a specific error can solve your problem but anyways I think [this](https://blog.idrsolutions.com/2015/04/javafx-mp3-music-player-embedding-sound-in-your-application/) can help you. And also I implemented it and works perfectly for me.

This is how I have done it:

```
List<Media> mediaList = new ArrayList<>();
FileManager files = new FileManager();
files.loadMediaFiles(new File("your music directory goes here.."));

files.getFiles().stream().forEach((media) -> {
    mediaList.add(new Media(media));
});


MediaPlayer mediaPlayer = new MediaPlayer(playList.get(0));
MediaView mediaView = new MediaView(mediaPlayer);

playPauseButton.setOnAction((ActionEvent event) -> {
        if (mediaPlayer.getStatus() == Status.PAUSED || mediaPlayer.getStatus() == Status.READY || mediaPlayer.getStatus() == Status.STOPPED) {
            mediaPlayer.play();
            playPauseButton.setGraphic(pause);
        } else {
            mediaPlayer.pause();
            playPauseButton.setGraphic(play);
        }
    });
```

You can also checkout my [app](https://github.com/ManOfGod/lazyCoder/tree/master/src/org/lazycodes) on github.