# ExceptionInInitializerError while adding labels to Layouts

Tags: java, exception, javafx

Today I have something, which should be a common task, but somehow I am getting Exceptions for it.
I have the following code:

```
public class ExampleScene extends Scene {

   public ExampleScene(Parent parent) {     
       super(parent,Variables.width,Variables.height);
   }

   public static Parent fill() {        
       HBox gp = new HBox();
       gp.getChildren().add(new Label("hi"));
       return gp;
   }
}
```

I'm calling them like this:

```
Parent par = ExampleScene.fill();
ExampleScene example = new ExampleScene(par);
```

But this produces the following exception:

```
Exception in thread "main" java.lang.ExceptionInInitializerError
    at de.rrcomtech.basicgui.test.ExampleScene.fill(ExampleScene.java:20)
    at de.rrcomtech.basicgui.test.startASimpleWindow.main(startASimpleWindow.java:18)

Caused by: java.lang.IllegalStateException: Toolkit not initialized
    at javafx.graphics/com.sun.javafx.application.PlatformImpl.runLater(PlatformImpl.java:396)
    at javafx.graphics/com.sun.javafx.application.PlatformImpl.runLater(PlatformImpl.java:391)
    at javafx.graphics/com.sun.javafx.application.PlatformImpl.setPlatformUserAgentStylesheet(PlatformImpl.java:673)
    at javafx.graphics/com.sun.javafx.application.PlatformImpl.setDefaultPlatformUserAgentStylesheet(PlatformImpl.java:635)
    at javafx.controls/javafx.scene.control.Control.<clinit>(Control.java:99)
    ... 2 more
```

The marked line is

```
gp.getChildren().add(new Label("hi"));
```

I cannot understand where is the fault in my code.

Comment: JavaFX is not initialised: See: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14025718/javafx-toolkit-not-initialized-when-trying-to-play-an-mp3-file-through-mediap/38883432

Comment: It looks like you are calling this before the JavaFX toolkit has been started (in particular, you seem to be calling this in a `main()` method). You need to call this in the proper place in the FX Application lifecycle. See, perhaps, https://docs.oracle.com/javase/10/docs/api/javafx/application/Application.html