# JavaFX Test That fails in Windows and works in OSX and Linux

Tags: java, linux, windows, macos, javafx

I have a JavaFX test that fails only in windows , but works fine in OSX and Linux

Here is the stacktrace :

> Edit : 1

```
Running com.myproject.meditor.SLIVCodeAreaTest
Tests run: 17, Failures: 0, Errors: 17, Skipped: 0, Time elapsed: 6.656 sec <<< FAILURE! - in com.myproject.meditor.SLIVCodeAreaTest
testRHBlock(com.myproject.meditor.SLIVCodeAreaTest)  Time elapsed: 0 sec  <<< ERROR!
java.lang.ExceptionInInitializerError: null
    at com.sun.glass.ui.Screen.getScreens(Screen.java:70)
    at com.sun.glass.ui.Screen.getMainScreen(Screen.java:61)
    at com.sun.javafx.font.PrismFontFactory.getSystemFontSize(PrismFontFactory.java:1911)
    at com.sun.javafx.font.PrismFontLoader.getSystemFontSize(PrismFontLoader.java:240)
    at javafx.scene.text.Font.getDefaultSystemFontSize(Font.java:71)
    at javafx.scene.text.Font.getDefault(Font.java:86)
    at javafx.scene.text.Text.getFont(Text.java:478)
    at javafx.scene.text.Text.getFontInternal(Text.java:487)
    at javafx.scene.text.Text.access$100(Text.java:95)
    at javafx.scene.text.Text$1.getFont(Text.java:206)
    at com.sun.javafx.text.GlyphLayout.breakRuns(GlyphLayout.java:174)
    at com.sun.javafx.text.PrismTextLayout.buildRuns(PrismTextLayout.java:770)
    at com.sun.javafx.text.PrismTextLayout.layout(PrismTextLayout.java:1021)
    at com.sun.javafx.text.PrismTextLayout.ensureLayout(PrismTextLayout.java:223)
    at com.sun.javafx.text.PrismTextLayout.getBounds(PrismTextLayout.java:246)
    at javafx.scene.text.TextFlow.computePrefWidth(TextFlow.java:203)
    at javafx.scene.Parent.prefWidth(Parent.java:915)
    at javafx.scene.layout.Region.prefWidth(Region.java:1419)
    at org.fxmisc.richtext.ParagraphBox.computePrefWidth(ParagraphBox.java:199)
    at org.fxmisc.richtext.ParagraphBox.computeMinWidth(ParagraphBox.java:191)
    at javafx.scene.Parent.minWidth(Parent.java:943)
    at javafx.scene.layout.Region.minWidth(Region.java:1383)
    at org.fxmisc.flowless.VerticalHelper.minBreadth(OrientationHelper.java:234)
    at org.fxmisc.flowless.OrientationHelper.minBreadth(OrientationHelper.java:44)
    at org.reactfx.collection.MappedList.get(MappedList.java:27)
    at org.reactfx.collection.MemoizationListImpl.force(MemoizationList.java:121)
    at org.fxmisc.flowless.SizeTracker.breadthFor(SizeTracker.java:161)
    at org.fxmisc.flowless.CellPositioner.getSizedCell(CellPositioner.java:130)
    at org.fxmisc.flowless.CellPositioner.placeStartAt(CellPositioner.java:95)
    at org.fxmisc.flowless.Navigator.placeStartAtMayCrop(Navigator.java:183)
    at org.fxmisc.flowless.Navigator.visit(Navigator.java:111)
    at org.fxmisc.flowless.StartOffStart.accept(TargetPosition.java:49)
    at org.fxmisc.flowless.Navigator.layoutChildren(Navigator.java:67)
    at javafx.scene.Parent.layout(Parent.java:1087)
    at org.fxmisc.flowless.VirtualFlow.layoutChildren(VirtualFlow.java:165)
    at javafx.scene.Parent.layout(Parent.java:1087)
    at org.fxmisc.flowless.VirtualFlow.visibleCells(VirtualFlow.java:138)
    at com.myproject.util.javafx.codearea.SEditor.<init>(SEditor.java:659)
    at com.myproject.util.javafx.codearea.SEditor.<init>(SEditor.java:607)
    at com.myproject.util.javafx.codearea.SCodeArea.<init>(SCodeArea.java:122)
    at com.myproject.meditor.SLICodeArea.<init>(SLICodeArea.java:124)
    at com.myproject.meditor.SLICodeArea.<init>(SLICodeArea.java:114)
    at com.myproject.meditor.SLItemCodeArea.<init>(SLICodeArea.java:106)
    at com.myproject.meditor.SLItemCodeArea.<init>(SLICodeArea.java:103)
    at com.myproject.meditor.SLIVCodeAreaTest.<clinit>(SLIVCodeAreaTest.java:14)
```

> EDIT: 2

From the stack trace, the part of code that triggered the exception  `(SLIVCodeAreaTest.java:14)` is in the declaration of `private static final SLIVCodeArea` in the part of code :

```
import static org.junit.Assert.assertTrue;
import org.junit.Test;

public class SLIVCodeAreaTest {     
    private static final SLIVCodeArea sEditor = new SLIVCodeArea(new SLICodeArea()) {

        @Override protected void updateVisibleParagraphRange() {}   };

    private static final VEditorProblemList sProblemList = 
        new VEditorProblemList(sEditor, new SimpleObjectProperty<>(), false);

    static { sEditor.aggregatedTextChanges().setAggregationEnabled(false); }
```

> Edit : 3

If I remove the keyword ***static*** from the initialisation part above , the stacktrace of the error becomes :

```
Running com.myproject.meditor.SLIVCodeAreaTest
Tests run: 17, Failures: 0, Errors: 17, Skipped: 0, Time elapsed: 1.124 sec <<< FAILURE! - in Running com.myproject.meditor.SLIVCodeAreaTest
testRHBlock(com.myproject.meditor.SLIVCodeAreaTest)  Time elapsed: 0 sec  <<< ERROR!
java.lang.RuntimeException: Internal graphics not initialized yet
    at com.sun.glass.ui.Screen.getScreens(Screen.java:70)
    at com.sun.glass.ui.Screen.getMainScreen(Screen.java:61)
    at com.sun.javafx.font.PrismFontFactory.getSystemFontSize(PrismFontFactory.java:1911)
    at com.sun.javafx.font.PrismFontLoader.getSystemFontSize(PrismFontLoader.java:240)
    at javafx.scene.text.Font.getDefaultSystemFontSize(Font.java:71)
    at javafx.scene.text.Font.getDefault(Font.java:86)
    at javafx.scene.text.Text.getFont(Text.java:478)
    at javafx.scene.text.Text.getFontInternal(Text.java:487)
    at javafx.scene.text.Text.access$100(Text.java:95)
    at javafx.scene.text.Text$1.getFont(Text.java:206)
    at com.sun.javafx.text.GlyphLayout.breakRuns(GlyphLayout.java:174)
    at com.sun.javafx.text.PrismTextLayout.buildRuns(PrismTextLayout.java:770)
    at com.sun.javafx.text.PrismTextLayout.layout(PrismTextLayout.java:1021)
    at com.sun.javafx.text.PrismTextLayout.ensureLayout(PrismTextLayout.java:223)
    at com.sun.javafx.text.PrismTextLayout.getBounds(PrismTextLayout.java:246)
    at javafx.scene.text.TextFlow.computePrefWidth(TextFlow.java:203)
    at javafx.scene.Parent.prefWidth(Parent.java:915)
    at javafx.scene.layout.Region.prefWidth(Region.java:1419)
    at org.fxmisc.richtext.ParagraphBox.computePrefWidth(ParagraphBox.java:199)
    at org.fxmisc.richtext.ParagraphBox.computeMinWidth(ParagraphBox.java:191)
    at javafx.scene.Parent.minWidth(Parent.java:943)
    at javafx.scene.layout.Region.minWidth(Region.java:1383)
    at org.fxmisc.flowless.VerticalHelper.minBreadth(OrientationHelper.java:234)
    at org.fxmisc.flowless.OrientationHelper.minBreadth(OrientationHelper.java:44)
    at org.reactfx.collection.MappedList.get(MappedList.java:27)
    at org.reactfx.collection.MemoizationListImpl.force(MemoizationList.java:121)
    at org.fxmisc.flowless.SizeTracker.breadthFor(SizeTracker.java:161)
    at org.fxmisc.flowless.CellPositioner.getSizedCell(CellPositioner.java:130)
    at org.fxmisc.flowless.CellPositioner.placeStartAt(CellPositioner.java:95)
    at org.fxmisc.flowless.Navigator.placeStartAtMayCrop(Navigator.java:183)
    at org.fxmisc.flowless.Navigator.visit(Navigator.java:111)
    at org.fxmisc.flowless.StartOffStart.accept(TargetPosition.java:49)
    at org.fxmisc.flowless.Navigator.layoutChildren(Navigator.java:67)
    at javafx.scene.Parent.layout(Parent.java:1087)
    at org.fxmisc.flowless.VirtualFlow.layoutChildren(VirtualFlow.java:165)
    at javafx.scene.Parent.layout(Parent.java:1087)
    at org.fxmisc.flowless.VirtualFlow.visibleCells(VirtualFlow.java:138)
    at com.myproject.util.javafx.codearea.SEditor.<init>(SEditor.java:659)
    at com.myproject.util.javafx.codearea.SEditor.<init>(SEditor.java:607)
    at com.myproject.util.javafx.codearea.SCodeArea.<init>(SCodeArea.java:122)
    at com.myproject.meditor.SLICodeArea.<init>(SLICodeArea.java:124)
    at com.myproject.meditor.SLICodeArea.<init>(SLICodeArea.java:114)
    at com.myproject.meditor.SLICodeArea.<init>(SLICodeArea.java:106)
    at com.myproject.meditor.SLICodeArea.<init>(SLICodeArea.java:103)
    at com.myproject.meditor.SLIVCodeAreaTest.<init>(SLIVCodeAreaTest.java:14)
```

> PS : The test worked in OSX with and without ***static*** keyword.

The same code works fine in Linux and MacOS, but fails in windows.
Does anyone have an idea why ?

Comment: Create and post a [MCVE].

Comment: Please include the *entire* stack trace in your question.  What line of code did you invoke that triggered the exception?

Comment: screens is a global or local variable ? and i think that your method _staticScreaan_getScreens_  returns null so your table has null elements.

Comment: @VGR  see Edit : 1 , Edit : 2 and Edit : 3 , I have added the stacktrace with the part of code that triggered the exception.

Comment: In all likelihood, hannoveraner is partly correct.  JavaFX simply will not work unless a javafx.application.Application instance has been initialized (by JavaFX, not by you).  You probably need to call [Application.launch](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/javafx/api/javafx/application/Application.html#launch-java.lang.Class-java.lang.String...-) from a method annotated with `@Before`.

Answer (score 0):

The combination of `JavaFX`, `JUnit` and any  `java.lang.ExceptionInInitializerError` is an indicator of an suppressed occurrence of the exception `Toolkit not initialized`.

To initialise JavaFX you may wait for `new JFXPanel()` to finish before running the unit test.

See:

- [JavaFX 2.1: Toolkit not initialized](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11273773/javafx-2-1-toolkit-not-initialized)

Comment: If the exception _Toolkit not initialized_ has occured, why it doesn't occur in MacOS or Linux ?

Comment: May depend on the JRE-Version used on MacOS, Linux or Windows.

Comment: What is a “suppressed occurrence” of an exception?  What leads you to believe this is a symptom of an uninitialized JavaFX Application?  I see nothing in the linked SO question which mentions any of the classes in the question’s stack trace.

Answer (score 0):

According to [Class ExceptionInInitializerError](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/lang/ExceptionInInitializerError.html)

> public class ExceptionInInitializerError extends LinkageError Signals
>   that an unexpected exception has occurred in a static initializer. An
>   ExceptionInInitializerError is thrown to indicate that an exception
>   occurred during evaluation of a static initializer or the initializer
>   for a static variable.

Because you did not post a  [Minimal, Complete, and Verifiable example.](https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve)
I think because  `newscreens`   is not **static** or is initialized by **null**,and you tried to transfer `null`variable to array.

Comment: Couldn't produce a Minimal Complete example as there a lot of dependencies, you are right about the fact that an exception has occurred during evaluation of a static initialiser, see my edits above