# JavaFX tests failing randomly

Tags: java, multithreading, unit-testing, javafx, junit

I have a JUnit Test Class that looks like the following :

```
public class HelloWorldApplicationTest {

private static TextArea mEditor = new HelloWorldApplication().getmEditor();

@BeforeClass
public static void initToolKit() throws InterruptedException {

    final CountDownLatch latch = new CountDownLatch(1);
    SwingUtilities.invokeLater(() -> {
        new JFXPanel(); // initializes JavaFX environment
        latch.countDown();
    });

    // That's a pretty reasonable delay... Right?
    if (!latch.await(5L, TimeUnit.SECONDS))
        throw new ExceptionInInitializerError();

}


@Test
public void testA(){
    mEditor.setText("111");
    assertTrue(mEditor.getText().equals("111"));
    mEditor.setText("qqq");
    assertTrue(mEditor.getText().equals("qqq"));
    mEditor.setText("eee");
    assertTrue(mEditor.getText().equals("eee"));
    mEditor.setText("aaa");
    assertTrue(mEditor.getText().equals("aaa"));
    mEditor.setText("aaa");
    assertTrue(mEditor.getText().equals("aaa"));
}

@Test
public void testB(){
    mEditor.setText("222");
    assertTrue(mEditor.getText().equals("222"));
    mEditor.setText("222");
    assertTrue(mEditor.getText().equals("222"));
    mEditor.setText("222");
    assertTrue(mEditor.getText().equals("222"));
    mEditor.setText("111");
    assertTrue(mEditor.getText().equals("111"));
}

@Test
public void testC(){
    mEditor.setText("333");
    assertTrue(mEditor.getText().equals("333"));
    mEditor.setText("333");
    assertTrue(mEditor.getText().equals("333"));
    mEditor.setText("TTT");
    assertTrue(mEditor.getText().equals("TTT"));
    mEditor.setText("333");

}
```

}

If I remove `initToolkit` method, tests will pass in Linux / OSX , but fail in windows throwing :

```
java.lang.ExceptionInInitializerError: null
        at com.sun.glass.ui.Screen.getScreens(Screen.java:70)
        at com.sun.glass.ui.Screen.getMainScreen(Screen.java:61)
        at com.sun.javafx.font.PrismFontFactory.getSystemFontSize(PrismFontFactory.java:1911)
```

Or , mEditor isn't a static variable.

```
java.lang.RuntimeException: Internal graphics not initialized yet
at com.sun.glass.ui.Screen.getScreens(Screen.java:70)
at com.sun.glass.ui.Screen.getMainScreen(Screen.java:61)
at com.sun.javafx.font.PrismFontFactory.getSystemFontSize(PrismFontFactory.java:1911)
```

(See : [JavaFX Test That fails in Windows and works in OSX and Linux](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/46026733/javafx-test-that-fails-in-windows-and-works-in-osx-and-linux) )

If I add `initToolkit` method, JavaFX environment get initialised, but tests start to fail randomly, and sometimes tests pass !
When I tested on a windows VM with a single processor , tests pass, which could describe here a multithreading issue over static editor ?
I've tried synchronized blocks (`synchronised(mEditor)`) , initializing JavaFX environement by refering to this thread : [How do you unit test a JavaFX controller with JUnit](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11385604/how-do-you-unit-test-a-javafx-controller-with-junit), but I always end up with this random behaviour, in which some tests pass, some tests fail and if run again tests could pass or fail randomly.